# showing value of enum in jsp using spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, enums, jstl

I have an enum

```
public enum Number
 {
 ONE("one"), TWO("two"), THREE("three"), FOUR("four");
 }
```

i put this enum into model

```
model.addAttribute("myEnum", Number.values());
```

Now, in jsp page I want to show a value of one of these enums.

```
<c:out value="${myEnum.ONE}"/>
```

but it doesnt seem to work. What am I doindg wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

myEnum is a list of values returned, you could either create one attribute equal to the value of one enum instance :

```
model.addAttribute("one", Number.ONE);

<c:out value="${one}"/>
```

or loop through myEnum :

```
<c:forEach items="${myEnum}" var="value">
    ${value}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Is there a solution where we can pass the actual enum instead of casting to an array, then iterating over the array until finding the value we want?